# Pass string to action method overload

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

So what I want to do is take a string from a textarea and pass it to an action method overload (string paramJSON).

Action method:

```
public ActionResult SendMail(string templateName, string receiver, string paramJSON)
{
    var paramDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(paramJSON);
    new SendMailClient().Send(templateName, receiver, paramDictionary);

    if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    { 
        return RedirectToAction("SendPartial", "TestMail");
    }
        return View();
}
```

Textarea:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.TestParametrar, new { id = "paramTxt" })
```

Comment: Rename the parameter to `TestParametrar` (to match the property your binding to). But why are not just binding to a model instead of 3 `string` parameters?

Comment: @StephenMuecke TestParametrar is the name of a model object that is inserted into the textarea through ID. That's why I don't think changing the name will do the trick.
Best practice here seems to be parsing the textarea for the string.

Comment: Of course it works - the `id` has nothing to do with it. When you submit a form, the form data that is posted is a series of name/value pairs based a controls `name` and `value` attributes. But the simplest way is just to post back your model -  public ActionResult SendMail(yourModel, model)` where `yourModel` is the same model used in the view - all its properties will be bound

Comment: @StephenMuecke I will try this and get back to you when I have.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you, this solved my problem. Please make it an answer so that I can mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html helper

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.TestParametrar, new { id = "paramTxt" })
```

generates a textarea with `name="TestParametrar"`. When you submit a form, it sends back the values of each controls `name` and `value` attributes in this case `TestParametrar: 'The text you entered'` You method needs to include a parameter with the same name, for example

```
public ActionResult SendMail(string TestParametrar, ....)
```

and the value of the parameter will be the text entered in the form control.

However, since you view is based on a model, then it is better to just post back to the model and all properties will be bound

```
 public ActionResult SendMail(YourModel model)
```

which has the added benefit of validating your properties. For example, if property `TestParametrar` has the `[Required]` attribute, then if the user does not enter a value, `ModelSTate` will be invalid and the view can be returned for correction.

Answer (score 0):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SendMail2"))
{
   @Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.TestParametrar, new { id = "paramTxt" })
   <input type="submit" value="Send Message" />
}
```

And:

```
public ActionResult SendMail2(string TestParametrar)
{
    return SendMail("myTemplate", "hello@world.com", TestParametrar);
}
```

Comment: How would a control with `name="TestParametrar"` bind to a parameter named `paramTxt`!

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer to make it correct help !

Comment: @Kilanny I will try this and get back to you when I have.